# What is the difference between Extended Role Based Access Control(Ex-RBAC) and Role Based Access Control(RBAC)?

Tags: linux, authorization, access-control, user-permissions, role-based-access-control

What is the difference between each, and when should I choose one over the other? Are there situations where these should be merged?
**Can you explain with an example which one is better and why?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what environment?

Comment: In an operating system kernel level access controlling based on policies defined